# After setting bounces = {false} scrolling of the screen is not smooth in react-native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I have set bounces = {false} in scrollview and Flatlist. After setting this I can't able to scroll the screen smoothly.

Any solution for this?

I am doing vertical scrolling in iOS. When I scroll the screen it gets bounced so I set bounces to false.

Refer the sample code

Note: It is a sample need to add lot of fields show as a large list

```
     <ScrollView bounces = {false}>
  <View style={{ aspectRatio: 4 / 5, alignSelf: 'center',width: '100%',  opacity: 0.5,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
              <FastImage resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain} style={{aspectRatio: 4 / 5, width: '100%',backgroundColor:'white'}} source={{ uri: 'item' }}/>
            </View>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> NAME </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> CLASS </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> AGE </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> GENDER </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> LOCALITY </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> EXPERIENCE </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> MOBILE NUMBER </Text>
                <Text style = {{fontSize:11, margin:"7%" }}> ALTERNATIVE NUMBER </Text>
              </ScrollView>
```

Comment: what problem in detail? the screen from vertical to horizontal and / or vice versa? Ios or Android or both ?

Comment: Write sample code so we will check and find issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `FlatList` instead? You can read about the differences and when to use one over another from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview)

Comment: What is your RN version?

Comment: @RezaGhorbani I am using react-native: 0.58.4

Comment: @VilleKoo I am using scrollview in some screens and Flatlist in other screens. For both the screens I have used bounces = {false} for oth the scroll

Comment: @sejn Have you tried setting `key` for ScrollView children? Setting keys helps ScrollView to not re-render when possible.

Comment: @RezaGhorbani Any references

Comment: @RezaGhorbani Are you suggest to add key for all the components inside the ScrollVIew

Comment: @sejn Yes. But if you could share your actual code I might be able to help you more.

Comment: @sejn You can also use native driver for animation. [link](https://blog.nativebase.io/butter-smooth-scrolling-animations-in-react-native-49edbba6a38a)

Comment: @RezaGhorbani I not need to show animation in my screen